# ODBC execute rows error and other errors

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I have no idea why am I getting these errors; the PHP code all looks fine to me.

> Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 50
>
> Warning: odbc_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 51
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 52
>
> Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 67
>
> Warning: odbc_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 68
>
> Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 81
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 82
>
> Warning: odbc_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 83
>
> Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 137
>
> Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\vote.php on line 138

#### vote.php source:

http://pastebin.com/duMFp3kJ

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and have a nice year!

Comment: Please, post your code direct [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14108235/edit)

Answer (score 2):

for example

```
$conn = odbc_connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=dbname", "username", "psw");
$sql = "SELECT user from user";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
```

you are done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your answer is basically correct (so I gave you +1), but could be improved by a bit more explanation of what you changed (the order of the parameters to [`odbc_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php)) and, ideally, a link to documentation to support your claim.  I think it might be worth documenting how you check that the connection succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite self-explained;

But if you still don't have clue, check out this [PHP document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php); it states that `odbc_exec` expects a connection resource returned by `odbc_connect` as its first parameter, not an `"SELECT..."` SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and it seem to be working now, but it's always giving me the same error that my account did not visted the shop yet, and it's not true, I don't know why, something with the fetch row or num rows is not working.

vote.php fixed:

http://pastebin.com/p4WWiyin

Comment: Probably much too late for your use case, but for anyone stumbling across this a decade later, most ODBC connectors don't have proper `odbc_num_rows` implementations and instead the function will _always_ return `-1` whether there are any results or not.